# How to return onClick value changed by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with submit button which calls submit Click function on on click. And if user enters nothing in input submit on click changes to nothing , but else statement which returns function if user enters all info is not working .

```
var r = document.getElementById("input1");
var r2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var r3 = document.getElementById("input3");
var r4 = document.getElementById("input4");

if (r.value === "" || r2 === "" || r3 === "" || r4 === "" ) {
    document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick="";
} else {
    document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick="submitClick()";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, when assigning a click listener via javascript, assign the actual function not a string with the function name. The string version is an HTML thing.

Also, I recommend not dynamically changing the function. Have the function include the validation logic for whether a click can or cannot happen. The benefit of this is you don't have to re-run your click listener assignment every time r1, r2, r3 or r4 changes.

Like so:

```
var r = document.getElementById("input1");
var r2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var r3 = document.getElementById("input3");
var r4 = document.getElementById("input4");

document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick = handleSubmitClick;

function canSubmitClick() {
    return !(r.value === "" || r2 === "" || r3 === "" || r4 === "")
}

function handleSubmitClick(e) {
    if( !canSubmitClick() ) {
        return;
    }

    submitClick(e);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. it helped. now i will try to understand why

Comment: and it needs r2.value 
r3.value
r4.value

Comment: one more question please

Comment: should i have 3 === or 2 ==

Comment: @LadoGelava I prefer 3 === as I generally know what data type I'm comparing. 2 == will do type conversion. Which can be useful when you expect it to happen but a pain to debug when you don't expect it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are setting `onclick` to a string, You should set it to function

```
document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick = submitClick;
```

I have two other suggestions for you

- Use same class for all inputs which have `id=r1,r2...`. And access it using `querySelectorAll()`
- Instead of checking each and values use `some()`.

Your code will look like.

```
var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.input')]
if (inputs.some(x => x.value === '')) {
    document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick="";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick=submitClick;
}
```

Comment: Love these new functions and features from ES6. Glad browsers are adding them quickly so we don't need too many polyfills

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that you forgot to check the value of r2, r3, and r4.

Then, you try to assign the onclick event to a string while it expects a function.

Just do:

```
document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick = submitClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead,i hope it will work:

```
var r = document.getElementById("input1");
var r2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var r3 = document.getElementById("input3");
var r4 = document.getElementById("input4");

if (r.value === "" || r2 === "" || r3 === "" || r4 === "" ) {
    document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick="";
} else {
    document.getElementById("sbmt").onclick = function() {submitClick()};
}
```

for more information check onclick tutorial on w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp